# Ember.js Router App Architecture -- How to have multiple nested view/controller pairs

Tags: javascript, architecture, ember.js, ember-old-router

I have an ember app and the concept of the outlet and connecting the outlet is fine, I get that. What I don't understand is how to have more than one view/controller view inside of another one without insane nesting

Suppose I am designing icloud clone where I have email functionality and a photo gallery functionality. Now if I wanted to accomplish something like

```
***********************************************************
* INBOX LIST     **  COMPOSE OR VIEW MESSAGE              *
*                **                                       *
*                **                                       *
*                **                                       *
*                **                                       *
* CONTACTS LIST  **                                       *
*                **                                       *
*                **                                       *
*                **                                       *
*                **                                       *
***********************************************************
```

The way that I would want to design this would be something like

```
EmailController/View
|-- SplitViewController/View
   |-- InboxListController/View
   |-- ContactsListController/View
   |-- ComposeMessageController/View
   |-- ReadMessageController/View
```

Where I can hot swap these to the level of the SplitView or remove them alltogether, but I don't see a good way of doing this with only one `outlet` allowed. It would force me next things inside of things that should not be nested. Using the single outlet approach, my structure would look more like

```
EmailController/View
|-- SplitViewController/View
   |-- InboxListController/View
       |-- ContactsListController/View
           |-- ComposeMessageController/View
               |-- ReadMessageController/View
```

How would I find an architecture style that fits with Ember.js/Router that still allows for more complex nesting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you know you can name the outlets ? For example, in SplitView template, you can have one {{outlet inboxListView}}, one {{outlet contactsListView}} etc... when you do your connectOutlets stuff, you can do this like:

```
splitViewController.connectOutlet({name: 'inboxList', outletName: 'inboxListView'})
splitViewController.connectOutlet({name: 'contactsList', outletName: 'contactsListView'})
```

and so on...

Comment: So then if you're using different named outlets for different views/model objects in SplitView, what would your router look like filling nested outlets with data? splitViewController.connectOutlet({name: 'inboxList', outletName: 'inboxList'}, router.get('store').findAll(App.Inbox))) and 
splitViewController.connectOutlet({name: 'contactsList', outletName: 'contactsList'}, router.get('store').findAll(App.Contact))) ?

Comment: smth like this yes, but have to put the context into the hash. `{name: 'contactsList', outletName: 'contactsList', context: router.get('store').findAll(App.Contact)})` see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ControllerMixin.html#method_connectOutlet for more details