# How to deal with dynamic content with Router?

Tags: dynamic, view, ember.js, router

I am developing an appliction by Ember.js, the application maintain categories, in the list view of categories, we will show the new cateogry form dynamically when users click the create button. Before using Ember's Router, we using the following mechanism:

View:

```
LCF.CategoriesView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'admin/app/templates/categories/list',
    isNewVisible:false,

    showNew:function () {
        this.set('isNewVisible', true);
    },

    hideNew:function () {
        this.set('isNewVisible', false);
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="well well-small">
   <a class="btn  btn-primary" href="#" {{action "showNewCategory"}}>Create</a>
</div>
{{#if view.isNewVisible}}
  {{view LCF.NewCategoryView}}
{{/if}}
```

After using router, the event will be handled by the route, and I changed the codes as following:

Router:

```
    categories:Em.Route.extend({
        route:'/categories',

        connectOutlets:function (router, context) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('categories', router.get('store').findAll(LCF.Category));
        },

        showNewCategory:function (router) {
            router.transitionTo('categories.newCategory', {});
        },

        index:Ember.Route.extend({
            route:'/'
        }),

        newCategory:Em.Route.extend({
            route:'/new',

            cancelEdit:function (router) {
                router.transitionTo('categories.index');
            },

            connectOutlets:function (router, context) {
                router.get('categoriesController').connectOutlet('editCategory', {});
                router.get('editCategoryController').enterEditing();
            }
        })
```

Template:

```
<div class="well well-small">
    <a class="btn  btn-primary" href="#" {{action "showNewCategory"}}>Create</a>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

It works.

My question is:

- Is it the proper way to dealing with the dynamic view? Do we need create a state/controller for every floating layer in the page?
- The URL will be changed even app still displays the categories.
- there is only one {{outlet}} in the template, if there are several dynamic view to display, how to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

- For me this looks pretty good. For the state creation and controllers... There is no yes/no answer here. Usually I would say you create a controller per context logic, and you create a route when you want to deal with a new application state. In your example, you do it well, with categories (state to have an overview of all categories), show (show a paricular category) ...
- What's the question here ? Sorry :s, I don't understand what you would like to know here.
- The answer is simple here, if you have several dynamic view to display in the page, you can use multiple {{outlets}}, using named outlets. see: [Ember.js Router App Architecture -- How to have multiple nested view/controller pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824917/ember-js-router-app-architecture-how-to-have-multiple-nested-view-controller/)

Comment: You're welcome. If you can clarify what you want in the second point, I'll try to answer :)

Comment: For the question 2:traditionally, in rails application, we will use the link http://xxx/categories to show all categories, then in the same page, we should the new category form, in that case, the url does not change. But when we use ember's router, after going in newCategory state, the url will be change to http://xxx/categories/new (this is used for a new page in rails). This looks ugly.